# The `.mongorc.js` is not found, but there is one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, client

When I start the mongo client `mongo.exe`, it prints out the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Wed Mar 12 11:15:47.013 In File::open(), CreateFileW for 'C:\Users\Zolt�n\.mongo
rc.js' failed with errno:3 The system cannot find the path specified.
Wed Mar 12 11:15:47.014 In File::len(), GetFileSizeEx for 'C:\Users\Zolt�n\.mong
orc.js' failed with errno:6 The handle is invalid.
Wed Mar 12 11:15:47.015 In File::read(), SetFilePointerEx for 'C:\Users\Zolt�n\.
mongorc.js' tried to set the file pointer to 0 but failed with errno:6 The handl
e is invalid.
>
```

As you see, my user path is `C:\User\Zoltán` and the character `á` is read as an unknown character. I bet this is the problem, why `mongo` can't find my `.mongorc.js`.

Is there any way I can explicitly set the path for `.mongorc.js`. Maybe with a configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet there isn't. There will be a "global" mongorc in future versions. For now you can "fake it" like so:

```
mongo --norc --shell fake.js
```

So you tell the shell to ignore looking for `.mongorc.js` then you pass in a javascript file just like you would if you wanted to run the contents.

The `--shell` parameter forces the return to "shell" after the `file` ("fake.js") has been evaluated.

So just put any valid JavaScript in that file and it will be treated like the entries in the standard `.mongorc.js`.

Answer (score 5):

`mongo --norc`  ignores the file, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error:

> 2017-10-02T12:54:21.435-0500 I STORAGE  In File::open(), CreateFileW for 'H:\.mongorc.js' failed with errno:3 The system cannot find the path specified.

I created directories `/data/db` under the location I was getting the error and it resolved the issue.

```
H:\>md data

H:\>cd data

H:\data>md db
```

I was able to connect without any issue once those directories were created.

```
H:\data>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15
connecting to: test
> db.names.insert({'name':'Mahrukh Khan'});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete `.mongorc.js` file using `sudo rm .mongorc.js` and the problem would be solved.